# Refunds and avoid duplicate payments with Paypal Payouts API

Tags: paypal

I'm working with the PayPal REST API for Payouts, and my problem is: I'm not able to find anything in the documentation if I want to reverse a payment when using Payouts.

I would also like to know if there is any way to avoid duplicate payments with this Payouts API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reverse (really, refund) a payout. Only the recipient can reverse it, so you would need [third party permissions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/third-party/) to each recipient's account to act on their behalf, if you wanted to undo a payout you sent to them.

For avoiding duplicate payments, there is some general documentation on idempotency: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/#api-idempotency

And for Payouts in particular, a unique `sender_batch_id` will not be processed more than once: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/